# How can I find the common name for a particular glyph?

Tags: terminal, special-characters

Sometimes, I'd like to know the name of a glyph. For example, if I see `−`, I may want to know if it's a hyphen `-`, an en-dash `–`, an em-dash `—`, or a minus symbol `−`. Is there a way that I can copy-paste this into a terminal to see what it is?

I am unsure if my system knows the common names to these glyphs, but there is certainly some (partial) information available, such as in `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose`. For example,

```
<Multi_key> <exclam> <question>         : "‽"   U203D # INTERROBANG
```

Another example glyph: .

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try the [unicode](http://kassiopeia.juls.savba.sk/~garabik/software/unicode/) utility:

```
$ unicode ‽
U+203D INTERROBANG
UTF-8: e2 80 bd  UTF-16BE: 203d  Decimal: &#8253;
‽
Category: Po (Punctuation, Other)
Bidi: ON (Other Neutrals)
```

Or the `uconv` utility from the [ICU](http://icu-project.org/download/latest_milestone.html) package:

```
$ printf %s ‽ | uconv -x any-name
\N{INTERROBANG}
```

You can also get information via the [`recode`](http://recode.progiciels-bpi.ca/) utility:

```
$ printf %s ‽ | recode ..dump
UCS2   Mne   Description

203D         point exclarrogatif
```

Or with Perl:

```
$ printf %s ‽ | perl -CLS -Mcharnames=:full -lne 'print charnames::viacode(ord) for /./g'
INTERROBANG
```

Note that those give information on the characters that make-up that glyph, not on the glyph as a whole. For instance, for `é` (e with combining acute accent):

```
$ printf é | uconv -x any-name
\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER E}\N{COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT}
```

Different from the standalone é character:

```
$ printf é | uconv -x any-name
\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE}
```

You can ask `uconv` to recombine those (for those that have a combined form):

```
$ printf 'e\u0301b\u0301' | uconv -x '::nfc;::name;'
\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE}\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER B}\N{COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT}
```

(é  has a combined form, but not b́).

Comment: What is `unicode`? I don't appear to have that installed (and can't find it in the Arch Linux repos). Also, what on earth is `exclarrogatif`? [EDIT: I get that here too, although my system is not French.]

Comment: @Sparhawk, contraction of `exclamatif` and `interrogatif`. `recode` was written by a French-Canadian guy in the early 80s.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Does `L` need in `CLS`? It makes the answer wrong if something like `LC_ALL` was set to non UTF8 locale.

Comment: @cuonglm, if you have LC_ALL=C, you have no business entering characters other than ASCII ones. If your locale is for instance `LC_ALL=fr_FR.iso885915@euro` and you enter `echo é | perl...`, that é will be written as 0xe9, not UTF-8 encoding. And you want perl to tell you about that é, not about UTF-8 characters that  won't be found in the input since the locale doesn't use that charset. Try `printf '\xe9' | _ALL=fr_FR.iso885915@euro perl...` for instance.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: I think in the OP's question, he know the symbol, he wants symbol to name. Just copy the symbol to terminal and get the name back. When pasting `‽`, he want `INTERROBANG` instead of `LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX` (when set LC_ALL=C).

Comment: @cuonglm, and what I'm saying is that if his locale is `LC_ALL=fr_FR.iso885915@euro` and he pastes `é` (0xe9 in that locale), `-CS` would give him the wrong answer.

Comment: Ah, got it. But `-CLS` doesn't always give the right answer as I shown in my above comment, right? Do we have any work around?

Comment: @cuonglm, -CLS with LC_ALL=C should give you the right answer for all the valid characters in the C locale. é and ‽ are usually not present in the C locale, there's no way you can express them there.

Comment: @Sparhawk http://kassiopeia.juls.savba.sk/~garabik/software/unicode/ — available as the `unicode` package on Debian, no idea about packaging on Arch.

Comment: Why printf instead of simply echo in the first some examples?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann [Why is printf better than echo?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803). Now that you asked, you're expected to read the whole answer. There will be a test.

Comment: @terdon thanks for the link, I did read it all.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but @StéphaneChazelas, what does the `%s` represent in some `printf` statements?

Comment: @Sparhawk `%s` is like a placeholder, called a format specifier (or conversion specifier). printf will replace it with the succeeding arguments, treating it as a string (as opposed to a number, for example) (generally how you would expect with C's `printf()` function). See the docs (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799//basedefs/V1_chap05.html).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Well, perl6 seems to be better in this case. It detect the Unicode characters by its graphemes, its codepoints, its encoding's code units, or the bytes that make up the encoding.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Perl [viacode function from charnames](http://perldoc.perl.org/charnames.html#charnames%3A%3Aviacode(_code_)) module:

```
$ printf ‽ | perl -Mcharnames=:full -CLS -nle 'print charnames::viacode(ord)'
INTERROBANG
$ printf  | perl -Mcharnames=:full -CLS -nle 'print charnames::viacode(ord)'
COW
```

[charnames](http://perldoc.perl.org/charnames.html) was first released with perl v5.6.0

---

With [Perl 6](http://www.perl6.org/) will be production ready on this Christmas day, it's worth to mention it here, since when it has the best support for Unicode characters I have ever seen. You only need to call [uniname](http://doc.perl6.org/routine/uniname) method/routine:

```
$ printf ‽ | perl6 -ne 'say .uniname'
INTERROBANG
```

`é` (e with combining acute accent) and standalone `é` character both give you:

```
# e with combining acute accent
$ printf é | perl6 -ne 'say .uniname'
LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE

# standalone é
$ printf é | perl6 -ne 'say .uniname'
LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE
```

(`.uniname` is the shorthand for `$_.uniname`)

Answer (score 5):

The best way I know is through Perl's `uniprops`. It comes with Perl's [`Unicode::Tussle`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unicode::Tussle) module. You can install it with

```
sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install Unicode::Tussle'
```

You can then run it on any glyph you want to test:

```
$ uniprops  ‽
U+203D ‹‽› \N{INTERROBANG}
    \pP \p{Po}
    All Any Assigned InPunctuation Punct Is_Punctuation Common Zyyy Po P
       General_Punctuation Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase Other_Punctuation
       Pat_Syn Pattern_Syntax PatSyn Print Punctuation STerm Term
       Terminal_Punctuation Unicode X_POSIX_Graph X_POSIX_Print X_POSIX_Punct

$ uniprops  
U+1F404 ‹› \N{COW}
    \pS \p{So}
    All Any Assigned InMiscPictographs Common Zyyy So S Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph
       GrBase Misc_Pictographs Miscellaneous_Symbols_And_Pictographs Other_Symbol
       Print Symbol Unicode X_POSIX_Graph X_POSIX_Print
```

Comment: `uniprops` also uses charnames::viacode internally.

Comment: @cuonglm yes, but the Tussle module includes all sorts of fancy tools and `uniprops` is far, far easier to type than explicitly calling the module. It also provides more info than just the name.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`unicode`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/unicode), which also outputs some more information than just the name:

```
# unicode –
U+2013 EN DASH
UTF-8: e2 80 93  UTF-16BE: 2013  Decimal: &#8211;
–
Category: Pd (Punctuation, Dash)
Bidi: ON (Other Neutrals)
```

Comment: What is `unicode`? I don't appear to have that installed (and can't find it in the Arch Linux repos).

Comment: @Sparhawk on my Debian, it's just a Python script installed by the `unicode` package. You should be able to get it by downloading the source package from the [Debian repos](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/unicode).

Answer (score 1):

Create a bash script with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F ":" '{print $2}' /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose | grep "$1" | awk -F "#" '{print $2}'
```

Name it as you want, for example, `namechar` and give it executing permissions.

Now, you can call for example:

```
./namechar @
```

and the result will be:

```
COMMERCIAL AT
```

Comment: This is good but only matches a susbset of characters, not full unicode. For example, it fails on ``, and produces repeated results for `€`. The last could be fixed by piping through `| sort -u`.

Comment: Yes, @terdon is correct. (That's why I said "partial" in the question.) This file only contains glyphs mapped to the `Compose` key.